# 2 different sites on 2 different ports not working. Apache

Tags: apache-2.2

I'm trying to host 2 different sites on 2 different ports: 80 and 8080.
I have currently set this up:

ports.conf

```
listen 80
listen 8080
NameVirtualHost *:80
NameVirtualHost *:8080
```

site1.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName my.site
...
```

site2.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
  ServerName a.my.site
...
```

Portscan tells me port 80 an 8080 are open and both have an http service.

`http://my.site` works and I get the desired site, but when I'm trying to connect to `http://my.site:8080`. I get `This site can't be reached. my.site refused to connect`

What did I do wrong?

(apache 2.2)

EDIT:

`http://(ip):8080` works.

I changed `site1` `site2`.
Now I tried `http://a.my.site` and it didn't work. Nor did `... :8080`.

Comment: `my.site` is not the same as `site1` or `site2` so it is difficult to understand your question and observations. Stop doing useless obfuscations, with the true names involved people could give you immediate relevant information. And if you obfuscate, please use RFC2606 guidelines to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check your `httpd.conf` and configure the website root, servername, etc.?
(In a default installation, you can find it in `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`.)

You can always have different websites with the same port number. 
Example:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerAdmin admin@site1.com
   DocumentRoot /root/site1
   ServerName site1.com
   ErrorLog logs/site1.com-error_log
   CustomLog logs/site1.com-access_log common
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerAdmin admin@site2.com
   DocumentRoot /root/site2
   ServerName site2.com
   ErrorLog logs/site2.com-error_log
   CustomLog logs/site2.com-access_log common
</VirtualHost>
```

In your case, check that you have configured the proper ports for each site in `httpd.conf`.

Comment: Well, There is a httpd.conf file. which is empty. I tried putting in listen 8080, but the it said that 8080 is already in use.

Comment: what version of apache are you using? 
Do you have /etc/apache2/apache2.conf ??

Comment: With Apache-2.2 you absolutely need a `NameVirtualHost` directive in such cases. It became obsolete with 2.3